# Определить поддержку Cool'n'Quiet (CPUID)

Tags: ассемблер, amd

Никак не могу найти информацию об определении поддержки технологии Cool'n'Quiet. Смотрел в официальных мануалах AMD (по CPUID), смотрел sandpile, в Яндексе и Google – приводят либо битые ссылки, либо какую-то инфу, которая противоречит другим мануалам (типа биты 1 и 2 в EDX cpuid Fn8000_0007, в sandpile и AMD CPUID Specification совсем другое написано).

В общем, буду признателен, если кто-то сможет пролить свет на этот тёмный лес... :)

Comment: смотрите ядро linux. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/cpufreq/powernow-k8.c?v=3.6  функция `check_supported_cpu`

Comment: @Mike, а PowerNow и Cool'n'Quiet - это одно и то же?

Comment: я просто посмотрел в гугле как включить в linux поддержку Cool'n'Quiet там было сказано загрузить драйвер powernow-k8. есть еще несколько модулей powernow но они судя по всему работают с другими вариантами. И в функции find_psb_table в k8 в случае если не удалось загрузить таблицу частот выдается сообщение "проверьте обновления BIOS и включена ли Cool'n'Quiet"

Comment: @Mike, ну вот CrystalCPUID каким-то образом определяет эту фичу и обозначает её как **PowerNow!/Cool'n'Quiet**, что наводит на мысли...

Comment: ну да, я думаю Cool'n'Quiet частный случай powernow

Comment: @Mike, вроде как получается, что всё-таки биты 1 и 2 в EDX функции 8000_0007 cpuid... хотя сомнения некоторые терзают всё же...